# Jenkins deploy WAR to Tomcat over SSH?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin for Jenkins that will wrap calls to Tomcat's Manager over SSH?

My company is about to deploy some apps "in the cloud", and we seem to be going to use Jenkins. The problem is, I am uncomfortable opening the Tomcat Manager to the Internet.

Alternatively, is it possible for Jenkins to open a VPN connection to the target server before deployment?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can write an Ansible script to do the job and use it in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you enable SSL for tomcat and put a reverse proxy in front of it?

your connector in your server.xml would look something like this:

-->

```
 <Connector  address="<localhost IP>" port="<port>" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
            ciphers="<Cipher1>,
                     <Cipher2>,
                     <Cipher3>" 
            keystoreFile="<keystore directory>"          
            keystorePass="<keystore password>"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
            connectionTimeout="120000"
            maxPostSize="-1"
            maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
            />
```

to deploy your war files you could use an xml file executed by ant in your jenkins script :

```
<project name="Deploy" default="deploy">
<path id="tomcat.class.path">
<fileset dir="<TomcatHome>/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
<pathelement location="<TomcatHome>/bin/bootstrap.jar"/>
<pathelement location="<TomcatHome>/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="tomcat-start">
    <echo>Stop Tomcat</echo>
<java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" fork="true" classpathref="tomcat.class.path">
    <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=<TomcatHome>"/>
</java>
<sleep seconds="15"/>
</target>

<target name="tomcat-stop" depends="tomcat-check-status" if="tomcat.started">
    <echo>Start Tomcat</echo>
    <java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"     fork="true" classpathref="tomcat.class.path">
<jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=<TomcatHome>"/>
        <arg line="stop"/>
    </java>
    <sleep seconds="15"/>
</target>

<target name="tomcat-check-status">
    <condition property="tomcat.started">
        <socket server="localhost" port="8000"/>
    </condition>
</target>
<target name="deploy">
    <sequential>
        <antcall target="tomcat-stop"/>
            <echo>Deploy to server</echo>
            <copy todir="<TomcatHome>/webapps">
                <fileset dir="<Current directory of WarFiles>">
                <include name="*.war"/>
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        <antcall target="tomcat-start"/>
    </sequential>
</target>
</project>
```

This is what your pipeline script might look like:

```
dir("<directory of build.xml>") {
       stage('deploy'){
         def antHome = tool 'Ant <version>';
                withAnt(installation: 'Ant <version>') {

            bat "ant deploy"
            }
        }
        }
    }
```